# Resize the signHere tabs of Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, signature

how to Resize the signHere tabs of Docusign using the restapi.
The size of tabs appear too big on width 1900 and height 4780 pdf file.

i tried with the "width" and "formatting" but doesn't work, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

SignHere tabs support the [ScaleValue parameter](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/create/#definition__enveloperecipienttabs_signheretabs_scalevalue), which can range from .5 (half size) to 2.0 (double size). If setting ScaleValue to .5 still results in tabs that are too big, you may need to resize the document. I find that using a PDF printer and scaling the document to fit on an 8.5 x 11 page generally results in something more appropriate.

Comment: Is that the case for the InitialsHere tabs as well ?

Comment: Yes, initial tabs support the `ScaleValue` parameter as well

Comment: And do they support the Width and Height ? The documentation (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/create/#definition__enveloperecipienttabs_signheretabs_width) mentions "Not Applicable to SignHere Tabs but don't mention the same for InitialHere Tabs. Is that a mistake in the doc ?

Comment: InitialTabs do not support `width` and `height`